# Accessing tuples in dictionary

Tags: python

I have this dictionary that stores pairs of two quiz scores and participants' ID. The structure is {(quiz1, quiz2): ID}

```
scoredict = {('83', '93'): '81937', ('88', '86'): '33576', ('96', '97'): '01084', 
('81', '95'): '48534', ('84', '72'): '11235', ('77', '80'): '01835', ('90', '83'): 
'39488', ('75', '74'): '31049', ('80', '62'): '10188', ('85', '86'): '63011', 
('66', '89'): '58272'}
```

I want to make this program to look up  for an ID by entering a pair of quiz scores. Like, for example, if the user input 83 and 93 for quiz 1 and quiz 2, it will return 81937. I've been working on this since the last 48 hours, but none of my codes worked...

And is it possible to find the closest available scores for both quizzes and print the ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I verified your solution already works with [ipython](http://ipython.org/):

```
In [1]: scoredict = {('83', '93'): '81937', ('88', '86'): '33576', ('96', '97'): '01084', 
   ...: ('81', '95'): '48534', ('84', '72'): '11235', ('77', '80'): '01835', ('90', '83'): 
   ...: '39488', ('75', '74'): '31049', ('80', '62'): '10188', ('85', '86'): '63011', 
   ...: ('66', '89'): '58272'}

In [2]: scoredict['83','93']
Out[2]: '81937'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the *closest* scores, you can try this:

```
test = (83, 93)

deviation = float('inf')
best_match = None

for score1, score2 in scoredict:
  error = abs(int(score1) - test[0]) + abs(int(score2) - test[1])

  if error < deviation:
    deviation = error
    best_match = (score1, score2)

print scoredict[best_match]
```

Comment: I tried to use this method but I got this error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-140.0'

Comment: Use `float()` instead of `int()` if you are using floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
>>> scoredict[(score1,score2)]
```